# Batched map for Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series consisting of text entries and want to apply a function that is quite slow to every element. That function however accepts batched inputs. Is there a way to leverage batching? Should I avoid `map` altogether?

Currently my code looks like this:

```py
series = series.map(slow_func)
```

Howerever `slow_func` also accepts batches like this:

```py
batched_out = slow_func([series[0], series[1], series[2])    # returns [out1, out2, out3]
```

Comment: Only 3 arguments or any arguments like `*args`?

Comment: Can your function accept a series instead of a list of strings (to keep the index)?

Comment: @Corralien the function accepts either a string or a list of strings. In reality it is a huggingface translation model, so putting it on GPU and using batches should speed up processing by quite a bit. Rigth now it seems to be best to just convert the series to a list and work with that, any thoughts on that?